# Branch current method of a circuit with phasors

Tags: phasor

i was trying to resolve this sample circuit:

I was trying to resolve a simple circuit with the branch current method, but my result doesn't match the exercise result.
[image: Circuit]

In fact, the phasor of the resistor R2 should be $$-0.01 - 0.70 j$$, while my result is:$$-0.8 -0.06 j$$

Setting, condisdering the bottom node,$$u_3=0$$

It becomes:
$$
\left\{\begin{matrix}
u_1= 10e^{-\frac{\pi}{4}j}\\ 
u_3=0 \\
I_E+ \frac{u_1}{2j} + \frac {u_1-u_2}{20}=0 \\ 
\frac {u_2 -u_1}{20} - \frac{u_2}{100j} + \frac{u_2}{20} = 2  \\ 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

The current of all the two-poles are directed to the node 3. R2 current goes from the first node (left) to the second one (right)

Then:
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
u_1= 10(\frac{\sqrt2}{2}-\frac{\sqrt2}{2}j)\\  
5j u_2 - 5j u_1 - u_2 + 5j u_2 = 200j  \\ 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
u_1= 5\sqrt2-5\sqrt2j\\  
10j u_2 - u_2 - 5j (5\sqrt2-5\sqrt2j) =200j  \\ 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

$$(10j - 1) u_2 -25\sqrt2j- 25\sqrt2 =200j$$

$$(10j - 1) u_2  =200j + 25\sqrt2j + 25\sqrt2$$

$$u_2  =\frac{200j + 25\sqrt2j + 25\sqrt2}{- 1 + 10j}$$

$$u_2  =\frac{200j + 25\sqrt2j + 25\sqrt2}{- 1 + 10j} \cdot \frac{-1 - 10j}{-1 - 10j}$$

$$u_2  =\frac{(200j + 25\sqrt2j + 25\sqrt2)(-1+10j)}{101}$$

$$u_2  =\frac{-200j - 25\sqrt2j - 25\sqrt2 + 2000 + 250\sqrt2 - 250\sqrt2j } {101}$$

$$u_2  =\frac{-200j + 2000 + 225\sqrt2 - 275\sqrt2j } {101}$$

$$u_2 \approx \frac{2318,91 - 589j } {101}$$

$$u_2 \approx 23.18 - 5.89j$$

$$i_2 = \frac{u_1 - u_2} {R_2}\approx \frac{7.07 - 7.07j-23.18 + 5.89j}{20}$$
$$i_2 \approx \frac{-16.01 -1.18j}{20}$$

$$ i_2 \approx -0.8 - 0.06j$$

So, my result is:
$$i(t)= 0.80 \cos (200t - 0.75)$$

Instead of:$$i(t)= 0.70 \cos (200t - 1.58)$$

EDIT: The resistor connected to the first and the second node is R2 , not R1. The resistor connected to the second and to the third node is R1.

Comment: It would be faster to apply superposition.

Comment: Yes, it (surely) is. But i have to apply this method (the exercise says so).

Comment: Can you maybe use thevenin for the RLC triangle plus the VS? Can you simulate it with whatever you want and see if the book is wrong? I don't think anybody here is going through your calculations.

Comment: As i said, i have to solve it with the branch current method.

Comment: The capacitor impedance (100j) looks to be incorrect.

Comment: I think it is correct.